# Not able to see search icon in light mode for android .net maui

Tags: .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I'm not able to see search icon in light mode for maui android.

[image]

Here is my code. let me know if i'm doing wrong anything here.

```
 <SearchBar WidthRequest="{Binding Source={x:Static local:App.screenWidth}}"  ios:SearchBar.SearchBarStyle="Default"  x:Name="SearchBar"  TextChanged="SearchBar_TextChanged" SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}" SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference SearchBar}}" Placeholder="Search">

                            <SearchBar.CancelButtonColor>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
                                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="White"/>
                                    <On Platform="Android" Value="White"/>
                                </OnPlatform>
                            </SearchBar.CancelButtonColor>
                            <SearchBar.PlaceholderColor>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
                                    <On Platform="Android" Value="White"/>
                                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="Gray"/>
                                </OnPlatform>
                            </SearchBar.PlaceholderColor>
                            <SearchBar.Margin>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                                    <On Platform="Android" Value="0, 6 , 0, 6"/>
                                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                                </OnPlatform>
                            </SearchBar.Margin>
                            
                            <SearchBar.TextColor>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
                                    <On Platform="Android" Value="White" />
                                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="White" />
                                </OnPlatform>
                            </SearchBar.TextColor>
                            <SearchBar.BackgroundColor>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
                                    <On Platform="Android" Value="{StaticResource 00dp}" />
                                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="{StaticResource 00dp}" />
                                </OnPlatform>
                            </SearchBar.BackgroundColor>
                        </SearchBar>
```

can someone please help here. thank you in advance!! :)

Answer (score 0):

> Not able to see search icon in light mode for android .net maui

This is because the search icon has the same color as the search bar's background color. So you can make their colors different to let the search icon be seen.

1. Change the SearchBar.BackgroundColor:

```
<SearchBar.BackgroundColor>
      <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
          <On Platform="Android" Value="DarkGray" />
          <On Platform="iOS" Value="{StaticResource 00dp}" />
      </OnPlatform>
</SearchBar.BackgroundColor>
```

2. Change the search icon color:

There is an issue about changing the search icon color in the .net maui.The `SearchBar` in the maui is the `AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.SearchView` in the native android. And for the `AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.SearchView`, you need to use the `AndroidX.AppCompat.Resource.Id.search_button` to get the searchview's search icon in the native android. But the `AndroidX.AppCompat.Resource.Id.search_button` doesn't exist in the .net maui.

So you can report an new issue for the .net maui on the github and change the SearchBar.BackgroundColor to make the search icon be able to see.

Comment: You are welcome and looking for your feedback. @VanjaraSweta